# Rectangle with looming border

Tags: svg

I want to create rectangle with smoothed border. Important part that size of it's solid part should be   certain. To clarify I'll give an example:

I can achieve desired effect with Gaussian filter:

```
<svg id="svg-root" width="800" height="600"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="test-body-content">
    <defs>
      <filter id="blur" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
       <feMerge>
         <feMergeNode in="blur" />
       </feMerge>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="200" height="100" fill="black" filter="url(#blur)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Result:

[image: rect1]

But it doesn't meet requirements because it is not fully solid within given dimensions (width="200" height="100"):

[image]

Also I thought about applying gradient perpendicular to stroke, but SVG doesn't support such thing.

Comment: you can add the original width and height with filter width

Comment: @ABFORCE, can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ABFORCE wrote you can provide the width and height you want via the `filter` element.

For example:

```
<filter id="blur" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" 
        x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
   ...
</filter>
```

Note that this means that above filter will be clipped to the boundingbox of the filtered element.

If you want the original shape in the filter output you could add another feMergeNode like this:

```
<svg id="svg-root" width="800" height="600"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g id="test-body-content">
    <defs>
      <filter id="blur" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
       <feMerge>
         <feMergeNode in="blur" />
         <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
       </feMerge>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="200" height="100" fill="black" filter="url(#blur)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/CC7qH/2/).

Comment: It almost what I needed. Can you explain what empty feMergeNode does?

Comment: It's the same as <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>, it puts the source graphic on top.

Comment: it looks like it's not the same. Look http://jsfiddle.net/HAMx5/, where I explicitly set <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>. Also it's not the same as absence of second merge node. Strange.

Comment: I must have been tired :) Yes, you're right. Leaving off the `in` parameter is the same as taking in the previous filter step output. I've updated the answer.